# JS Regex named groups with replace()

Tags: javascript, php, css, arrays, regex

In JS, I'm trying to build an object from the below code. However I'm stuck at getting regex named groups with the below replace function.

```
var formatters = {
    'p': 'padding',
    'm': 'margin',
    'd': 'border',  // Had to use letter "d", Becuase "b" means "bottom".
    't': '-top',
    'b': '-bottom',
    'l': '-left',
    'r': '-right'
}

var str = 'p:[p], pt:[p][t], pb:[p][b], rounded-tr:[d][t][r]-radius'

var match = str.replace(/:(?<selection>.*?)(:?,)/g, (m) => formatters[m])

// var expectedOutput = {'p':'padding', 'pt':'padding-top', 'pb':'padding-bottom', 'rounded-tr': 'border-top-right-radius'}
```

**NOTE:** What I'm trying to do is, Select characters from *str* variable from ":" to "," and replace it with *formatters* values. Then make the string an object.

Comment: The logic of mapping presumable keys is ambiguous. How do you know that initial (or trailing one, for that matter) `'r'` in `'rounded-tr'` shouldn't be converted to `'-right'`?

Comment: How could you get `expectedOutput`  like an object using replace()?

Comment: Yevgen: Ah, That's an issue. Maybe wrap each replaceable characters in '[ ]' ? Like this: `rounded-tr:[d][t][r]-radius` ?

Comment: @stackminu: not very elegant, but that might work (if you're not supposed to have neither `'['`, nor `']'` in your output and your totally in control of what is passed in as a `str`).

Comment: User863: That's simple, Can do with `map` and `join`. Will demonstrate after figuring out the regex part.

Comment: @stackminu then it should not necessarily a part of a question.

Comment: Yevgen: I updated the question. Regex needs to to be updated accordingly to catch letters inside `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UPBmho/1/)**

```
\[([a-z])\]
```

```js
var formatters = {
  'p': 'padding',
  'm': 'margin',
  'd': 'border', // Had to use letter "d", Becuase "b" means "bottom".
  't': '-top',
  'b': '-bottom',
  'l': '-left',
  'r': '-right'
}

var str = 'p:[p], pt:[p][t], pb:[p][b], rounded-tr:[d][t][r]-radius'

var match = str.replace(/\[([a-z])\]/g, (m, p1) => formatters[p1])

console.log(match)

var expectedOutput = Object.fromEntries(match.split(', ').map(s => s.split(':')))

console.log(expectedOutput)
```